# Matrix as user input in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, user-input, linear-algebra

In Julia, the function **readline()** can accept user input, but such user inputs are always cast to the string type by the readline() function. Is there any way to accept user input of **multidimensional arrays/matrices**, such that they won't automatically be cast as strings?

Answer (score 1):

For reading in matrices, you can use the `readdlm` function from the DelimitedFiles standard library. It accepts values separated by a delimiter (default: whitespace) for each row, and the rows themselves are separated by an end-of-line character (default: `\n`).

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm(stdin)
1 2 3
4 5 6
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 4.0  5.0  6.0
```

`readdlm(stdin)` accepts user input until the EOF (End-Of-File) character is pressed (Ctrl-D on Linux, I believe Ctrl-Z on Windows). You can also pass in the expected element type of the input, and a `Matrix` of that type will be returned (or an error raised, if the input wasn't of that type).

```
julia> readdlm(stdin, Int)
1 3 5
7 9 11
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3   5
 7  9  11

julia> readdlm(stdin, Int)
1 3.14 5
7 9 11
ERROR: at row 1, column 2 : ErrorException("file entry \"3.14\" cannot be converted to Int64")
```